# Using Rails helpers in Haml files in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use the rails helper method `render` in order to use my haml templates that I will use throughout my web app. I have those templates in `app/assets/javascripts/app/templates`.

After some searching I end up with a possible solution (adding it in a ruby initializer file):

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include HamlHelper
end

Tilt.register CustomHamlEngine::HamlTemplate, '.haml'
```

Now it seems that the render method is being used but now there's another error:

```
undefined local variable or method `view_renderer' for #<#<Class:0x00000102baf740>:0x00000102c876e0>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to put haml-files into a javascript-assets-folder? What's wrong with hamls' natural habitat the app/view - folder?

Comment: Basically I'm working on an angularjs application and all the views will be handled by angular not rails. Now, I know I can use angular's ng-include but that's not what I want. I want to be able to use Rails `render` so I can use my haml templates to generate the views.

Comment: I am not that deep into angular, but you still could use the usual rails way with the haml files and get them via ajax calls, for example. You might also run into problems, since the assets don't see any controller variables. At least, if this hasn't changed in Rails 4.

Comment: I'm not interested in using controller variables in the templates inside the assets folder. I just need the flexibility of the render method in the assets. I also tried creating a custom render method, but it doesn't allow the templates to use other rails helpers like image_tag (that only work with assets per se).

Comment: Well, basically nothing will work there. It's static code, which belongs into the assets. JS (there), CSS and Images are not meant to be built dynamically. It surely is somehow possible to twist rails arm and let him do things defying convention. But that's not my expertise, and I'd advise against it, since it's not necessary, IMHO.